# Lightning: What is the difference between ltng:require and aura:clientLibrary

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

What is the difference between [ltng:require](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm) and [aura:clientLibrary](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/ref_tag_clientlibrary.htm)?

What are the best practices with regard to their usage?

What are the technical concerns that should be taken into account when choosing either of them.

I see that `combine` on `aura:clientLibrary` allows to can improve performance by reducing the number of requests

Answer (score 6):

`ltng:require` is used to refer javascripts and CSS only from static resource and we can decide sequence in which javascript should be loaded.

Whereas `aura:clientLibrary` allows external Javascript even from URL as well as CSS files.

Comment: `ltng:require` totally can handle CSS, but the point is correct that `require` must load from a static resource.

Answer (score 1):

Use ltng:require instead of aura:clientLibrary.

Per the doc: The framework’s content security policy mandates that external JavaScript libraries must be uploaded to Salesforce static resources. See https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_libs_platform.htm