# Load CSS and JS from CDN in Lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components

How can i use external JS and CSS stored at CDN in lightning components?
I believe aura:clientLibrary is the tag to do the same. But i couldn't find its documentation to use it. Am refering the below mentioned stackexchange question to load the css.

[Lightning: What is the difference between ltng:require and aura:clientLibrary](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/80852/lightning-what-is-the-difference-between-ltngrequire-and-auraclientlibrary)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To reference an external CSS resource, use a `<ltng:require>` tag. But I believe you can not add files from CDN. As per [Salesforce documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2015/05/loading-external-js-css-libraries-lightning-components.html) "**CDNs are not allowed at this point** because they are outside of Salesforce data centers and can’t be controlled." This has more stringent security requirements, in that you have to load the JavaScript via a static resource rather than an external CDN from the likes of Google or Microsoft.

Comment: I agree,then why there is aura:clientLibrary and stackoverflow answer stating we can load from external domain.

Comment: An old question, but I thought I'd add an update.  You can access external CDNs, as of the Winter '17 release, with <ltng:require>.  Not sure about prior releases.

Comment: can you write new answer with description? So I can mark it as correct and everyone will be able to benefit from it?