# Place external JS in head of community?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, community, lightning-community

We would like to use/build community using communities lightning. The problem we encounter is that there is no possibility to add any javascript from external resource/CDN.

The issue is that this is the only way you use 99% of marketing tools. The problem we encounter is related to Blueconic - automated profiling tool.

I know there is an option to store JS in static resources and load this way - but still this cannot be done in the head section. Am I correct? For me actually means show stopper and one client for SF less.

I have seen [Load CSS and JS from CDN in Lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/load-css-and-js-from-cdn-in-lightning-component). Mentioned topic is not solved and what is important in my situation external resources must be loaded in the HEAD section of the page - NOT in component - so it's different place in the platform.

Comment: You can add a VF page component in Lightning and include resource/CDN functionality within that to integrate with the systems you wish. Basically VF pages act as iframes within lightning components

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Load CSS and JS from CDN in Lightning component](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/96256/load-css-and-js-from-cdn-in-lightning-component)

Comment: It is duplicate with the one above - according to one of the comments it should be possible - but no confirmation - that is why I created new topic.

Comment: Also there were updates to lightning and communities since then

Comment: @RedDevil we are talking about marketing/ tracking tools - loading in iframe it's not an option at all. Please be aware that those scripts need to be loaded after 1st <head> tag

Comment: Yeah, I read the comment as well, but there is no supporting documentation. I even did a quick research. and the documentation still states that this is not an available feature at the moment

Comment: But as I said the mentioned topic was about components - these part is already in the body section - I think edit markup should be the place to do it - but it seems like it's impossible to put ANY js tags there anymore - whiles in '16 (I assume before locker service) this was possible

Comment: my bad i did not interpret the comment properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of Summer '17  with locker service and with "Enable Stricter CSP for Lightning Components" Enabled it will no longer be supported. the [documentation](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/latest/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/community_templates.pdf) lists supported tags and attributes as well as an IMPORTANT note.

> Important: With the "Enable Stricter CSP for Lightning Components in
>   Communities" critical update, you have control over whether to enforce
>   stricter CSP. When stricter CSP is activated, some of your existing
>   head markup may not work correctly. Test your markup in your sandbox
>   or DE orgs first before activating in live orgs in a future release.
>
> For security purposes, we restrict the tags, attributes, and values
>   allowed in the head markup of your pages
>
> `<base>`
>
> Allowed Attributes:
>
> href, target
>
> `<link>`
>
> Allowed Attributes:
>
> as, charset, crossorigin, disabled, href,
>   hreflang, id, import, integrity, media, rel, relList, rev, sheet,
>   sizes, target, title, type
>
> **For rel, allowed values are alternate:
>
> apple-touch-icon, apple-touch-icon-
>   precomposed, apple-touch-startup-image, author, bookmark, external,
>   help, icon, license, manifest, mask-icon, next, nofollow, noopener, 
>   noreferrer, pingback, prefetch, preload, prev, search, shortcut icon,
>   stylesheet, and tag.
>
> `<meta>`
>
> Allowed Attributes:
>
> charset, content, http-equiv,2  name, scheme
>
> **For http-equiv, allowed values are cleartype, content-type,
>   content-language, and default-style.
>
> `<title>`
>
> None allowed

If you do add scripts you will get the following message:

[image]

You will have to monitor and check for critical updates and decide which ones to enable/disable.

Comment: Actually [it looks like you can disable the stricter CSP](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=community_builder_page_head.htm&language=en_US&type=0).

Comment: =P still updating the answer, but indeed, I will include the Note!

Comment: How shall I read this? Does it mean that we will be able to use external CDN? It seems like this is an issue for me with Blueconic. I cannot move their script locally - they do not allow, I cannot use external CDN because it is not allowed by SF....

Comment: Not recommended, however, you can if Stricter Content Security Policy for Lightning Components in Communities is disabled

Comment: I can confirm what has been said before. Since Summer '17 it is (again) possible to use js script served from external CDN - also in the header. This will be valid till Winter '19 (communities).

In my opinion Salesforce this is not only a time for us to fix our scripts but also for Salesforce to find a safe way to keep this functionality.

Thanks for all responses.

Comment: Maybe one addition: https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer17/release-notes/rn_lightning_stricter_csp.htm

Comment: Thanks Robert. I will add the link in the answer for reference purposes